# Change of variables in a double integral - how to find the region??

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have the following question:

> Calculate the double integral $\int \int _D (x^4-y^4) e^{xy} dx dy $ on the region $D$, which is the set located in the first quadrant, bounded by the hyperbolas $xy=1, \quad x^2-xy-y^2=1, \quad x^2-y^2 =3 $.

My questions are:
It is obvious that I need to use the following change of variables: $u=x^2-y^2 , \quad v=xy$ , and once I draw the region $D$ in the xy plane, I know how to find the boundaries. But -

> Is it possible to deduce the correct boundaries of the set $D^*$, which is the set $D$ in the $uv$ plane, without drawing the set $D$ in the xy plane?

If so, will you please help me understand how to do it?  When I draw the boundaries $u=3, \quad u-v=1, \quad v=1$ in $uv$ plane, I have two possible regions for $D^*$ , and have no idea how to choose between the two (without the drawing of $D$ )

Hope I made myself clear

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a region bounded by these three. And you donot need to draw region in XY plane. That is why you have changed variables

Comment: How did you get two possible regions? There is only one.

Comment: In the uv plane , the two regions are:

1. Above $v=1$
2. Below $v=1$, and above $v=0$ ... How can I deduce which is the correct region? Will you please help me? Thanks!